# Itunes Connect updated images - Clarify

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app waiting for review, its been 8 days so far but i decided to change the preview images.

Simply all I did was remove all images and upload new ones. i did not resubmit any builds or change anything else. Now when I go onto my app (via iPhone iTunes connect) it says something *4 hours ago* does this mean I need to wait another 10 days or so because I changed images? When I click status it still says waiting for review may 29th 2015

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your app is waiting for review, you can change things like screenshots and the app description, and it shouldn't affect your position in line.